# How do i get the current file name using ant build file?

Tags: xslt, ant

I recently created an ANT build file to transform a .xml file to .fo using xslt. And the ANT build performs as designed. However, the input file is hard coded into the XSLT task.

How do i dynamically change the input file name without having to edit the build file each time? The following is a snippet of my code.

```
<target name="createFO"
    description="Transform using XSLT 1.0" depends="clean, copyimg, copysrc">
      <xslt basedir="${srcdir}" 
            destdir="${dstDir}"
            extension=".fo"
            style="${ss}/foobar.xsl"
            in="sample.xml"
            out="${dstDir}/new.fo"/>   

      <echo>The fo file has been created!</echo>
</target>
```

I failed to mention that i am using OxygenXML to process my ANT file. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `in` and `out` attributes. Instead, you can use a `<fileset>` that contains the file you want to transform.

`<xslt>` will strip the suffix from your input file and apply the suffix used in the `extension` attribute.

```
<target name="createFO"
    description="Transform using XSLT 1.0" depends="clean, copyimg, copysrc">
    <!-- Don't put "basedir" parameter. It comes from fileset! -->
      <xslt destdir="${dstDir}"
            extension=".fo"
            style="${ss}/foobar.xsl">
            <fileset dir="${xslt.dir}"/>
      </xslt>
      <echo>The fo file has been created!</echo>
</target>
```

You can also use [mappers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) to transform the input file's name into the output file name too.

The other, of course is to use a property for the input file name, and then have someone pass the name of the file into the Ant script:

```
<target name="createFO"
    description="Transform using XSLT 1.0" depends="clean, copyimg, copysrc">
      <fail message="You must pass in the parameter &auot;-Dxml.file=...&quot;">
           <condition>
               <not>
                   <available file="${xml.file}">
           </condition>
      </fail>

      <xslt basedir="${srcdir}" 
            destdir="${dstDir}"
            extension=".fo"
            style="${ss}/foobar.xsl"
            in="${xml.file}"
            out="${dstDir}/new.fo"/>   

      <echo>The fo file has been created!</echo>
</target>
```

Now, to run this, you'd do:

```
$ ant -Dxml.file=sample.xml createFO
```

Comment: The first options listed may work, but for some reason the code wants to transform all file types in @basedir. The goal is to be able to run this build file against the currently opened file without having to edit the build file each time. I look forward to your comments.

Comment: My bad. You don't use `basedir` attribute when you use fileset. Otherwise, it'll use `basedir` as the directory as well as the `<fileset/>`. Does that help?

Comment: hmmm... removing the basedir did not do the trick either. On your second example, how do i pass the param?

Comment: When you run your program from the command line, you can pass in the property value on the command line. as shown below the example.

Comment: Great thanks. Once i defined the param ${xml.file} in Oxygen it works as expected! Now i can run the build file for any xml file without changing the build file.